# easiest way to convert objects in json to arrays in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have an json in python3 like this:

```
{
    "main": 2017,
    "titles": {
        "first": {
            "theone": 1,
            "thetwo": 2
        },
        "second": {
            "news": ["BBC", "CNN"],
            "olds": 1990
        },
        "ticker": ["A", "B", "C"]
    }
}
```

I need to change json object "titles" to json array "titles" like this:

```
{
    "main": 2017,
    "titles": [
        "first": {
            "theone": 1,
            "thetwo": 2
        },
        "second": {
            "news": ["BBC", "CNN"],
            "olds": 1990
        },
        "ticker": ["A", "B", "C"]
    ]
}
```

Please tell me - what is the easiest way to make this change in Python 3?

Comment: Please fix your syntax error.

Comment: thanks Josh, error in json is fixed

Comment: Your second example is neither valid JSON nor Python.

Comment: wow, thanks, I see - jsonlint says about parse error on line 4. it seems like restrinction of json standard which I did not know.